# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system while passing bitmap through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, parcel

I am trying to share image to other apps through `Intent`. This is my logic:

```
public void doSocialShare(String title, String text, Bitmap resource) {

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, resource);
        sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        sendIntent.setType("image/*");

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            Log.d("INFORMATION", "The current android version allow us to know what app is chosen by the user.");

            Intent receiverIntent = new Intent(this, ShareBroadcastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, receiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            sendIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share via...", pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
        }
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
```

This is how I am calling `doSocialShare()` method:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) img_FPO.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 30, out);
                Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));

                doSocialShare("Share To", "#Smile", decoded);
```

But I am getting this error. Its because of the bitmap size. How can I solve this ?:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.aligntech.myinvisalign, PID: 31495
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1533)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4403)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4362)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:732)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4686)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4654)
                                                                                at com.aligntech.myinvisalign.Activities.PhotoDetailActivity.doSocialShare(PhotoDetailActivity.java:800)
                                                                                at com.aligntech.myinvisalign.Activities.PhotoDetailActivity$3.onShareItemClick(PhotoDetailActivity.java:745)
                                                                                at com.aligntech.myinvisalign.Adapters.HorizontalRecyclerAdapter$3.onClick(HorizontalRecyclerAdapter.java:138)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6265)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23764)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                             Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 7991424 bytes
                                                                                at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:628)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3563)
```

UPDATE:

This is how I am getting the Uri from Bitmap. But instead of `getExternalDir()` I want to use `getCacheDir()`. How can I achieve that?:

```
public Uri getBitmapFromDrawable(Bitmap bmp) {

        // Store image to default external storage directory
        Uri bmpUri = null;
        try {
            // Use methods on Context to access package-specific directories on external storage.
            // This way, you don't need to request external read/write permission.
            // See https://youtu.be/5xVh-7ywKpE?t=25m25s
            File file = new File(PhotoDetailActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.close();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                // wrap File object into a content provider. NOTE: authority here should match authority in manifest declaration
                bmpUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(PhotoDetailActivity.this, "com.aligntech.myinvisalign.fileprovider", file);  // use this version for API >= 24
            } else {
                bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            }

            // **Note:** For API < 24, you may use bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmpUri;
    }
```

Comment: Asked multiple times ... your Bitmap is too big to pass it via Intent ... edit: not mention that EXTRA_STREAM should be an Uri

Comment: Then I have to write the bitmap somewhere to get Uri out of it.Which I dont want to do. @Selvin

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do ... hint: you should use FileProvider to get not a "file:///" uri

Comment: Okay. Can I use cacheDir for writing the image. Is it safe(writing with or without permission)? @Selvin

Comment: Yes, but as I wrote you nned to use FileProvider for two reasons: other apps cannot use your app's cache folder, 2nd reasosn is to not use "file://" uri

Comment: save you bitmap in your filesystem. pass an `Uri` to EXTRA_STREAM using `ContentProvider`.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: @Selvin I have updated my code with `FileProvider`. But I am not able to use `cacheDir()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is my logic

[The documentation for `EXTRA_STREAM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM) says that the value is a "content: URI holding a stream of data associated with the Intent". It does not say the value is "a Bitmap". You need to supply a `Uri` in this extra, from which other parties can get a stream (using a `ContentResolver`) to obtain your data. And then, the data needs to be in the format specified in your MIME type of the `Intent`, and a `Bitmap` does not have a MIME type (let alone a *wildcard* MIME type).

> This is how I am getting the Uri from Bitmap. But instead of getExternalDir() I want to use getCacheDir(). How can I achieve that?:

Step #1: Replace:

```
File file = new File(PhotoDetailActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
```

with:

```
File file = new File(getCacheDir(), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
```

Step #2: Use `FileProvider.getUriForFile(PhotoDetailActivity.this, "com.aligntech.myinvisalign.fileprovider", file);` for all API levels, as otherwise the other app cannot access your content

Step #3: Make sure that your `FileProvider` metadata XML resource is set up with a `<cache-path>` element

Step #4: Use `image/jpeg` in the MIME type of your `Intent` (not a wildcard), since you are saving this image as a JPEG

Comment: Currently I am using `getExternalCacheDir()`. its working perfectly. But I would like to know if there is any advantage of using `getCacheDir()` over `getExternalCacheDir()` ? If it looks more advantageous then I will go for `getCacheDir()`

Comment: @XoXo: `getCacheDir()` is private to your app. `getExternalCacheDir()` is merely unique for your app; other apps (and the user) can access its contents.